Unable to load model after saving it as .keras
I'm having an issue when I try to load a model I just saved, let me show you the code.
I loaded a pretrained model
pretrained = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50(include_top = False, 
                                      input_shape = (224,224,3), 
                                      pooling = 'avg',
                                      classes = 525,
                                      weights = 'imagenet' 
                                           )

for layer in pretrained.layers: #configurar capas para no entrenar
    layer.trainable = False


I creat my model based on the pretrained model
model = keras.Sequential()


model.add(pretrained) 
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(512, activation = 'relu', name = 'capa_1'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(525, activation = 'softmax', name = 'capa_de_salida'))

I train the model and get a 90% accuracy
opt = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = 5.5e-05)
model.compile(optimizer = opt, loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(train_dataset,
               epochs = 10,
               validation_data = val_dor)

but once I save it and try to load it, it wont work
path_model = './ResNet50_trans_learning_final.keras'
model.save(path_model)

modelo2 = tf.keras.models.load_model(path_model, compile=False)

I get this
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[102], line 5
      1 model.save('ResNet50_trans_learning_final.keras')
      3 path_model = './ResNet50_trans_learning_final.keras'
----> 5 modelo2 = tf.keras.models.load_model(path_model, compile=False)
      6 # hay un problema causado por la capa flaten y nose pude leer

File /usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/keras/src/saving/saving_api.py:176, in load_model(filepath, custom_objects, compile, safe_mode)
    173         is_keras_zip = True
    175 if is_keras_zip:
--> 176     return saving_lib.load_model(
    177         filepath,
    178         custom_objects=custom_objects,
    179         compile=compile,
    180         safe_mode=safe_mode,
    181     )
    182 if str(filepath).endswith((".h5", ".hdf5")):
    183     return legacy_h5_format.load_model_from_hdf5(filepath)

File /usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/keras/src/saving/saving_lib.py:155, in load_model(filepath, custom_objects, compile, safe_mode)
    153 # Construct the model from the configuration file in the archive.
    154 with ObjectSharingScope():
--> 155     model = deserialize_keras_object(
    156         config_dict, custom_objects, safe_mode=safe_mode
    157     )
    159 all_filenames = zf.namelist()
    160 if _VARS_FNAME + ".h5" in all_filenames:

File /usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/keras/src/saving/serialization_lib.py:711, in deserialize_keras_object(config, custom_objects, safe_mode, **kwargs)
    709 with custom_obj_scope, safe_mode_scope:
    710     try:
--> 711         instance = cls.from_config(inner_config)
    712     except TypeError as e:
    713         raise TypeError(
    714             f"{cls} could not be deserialized properly. Please"
    715             " ensure that components that are Python object"
   (...)
    719             f"\n\nconfig={config}.\n\nException encountered: {e}"
    720         )

File /usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/keras/src/models/sequential.py:336, in Sequential.from_config(cls, config, custom_objects)
    331     else:
    332         layer = serialization_lib.deserialize_keras_object(
    333             layer_config,
    334             custom_objects=custom_objects,
    335         )
--> 336     model.add(layer)
    337 if (
    338     not model._functional
    339     and build_input_shape
    340     and isinstance(build_input_shape, (tuple, list))
    341 ):
    342     model.build(build_input_shape)

File /usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/keras/src/models/sequential.py:117, in Sequential.add(self, layer, rebuild)
    115 self._layers.append(layer)
    116 if rebuild:
--> 117     self._maybe_rebuild()
    118 else:
    119     self.built = False

File /usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/keras/src/models/sequential.py:136, in Sequential._maybe_rebuild(self)
    134 if isinstance(self._layers[0], InputLayer) and len(self._layers) > 1:
    135     input_shape = self._layers[0].batch_shape
--> 136     self.build(input_shape)

File /usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/keras/src/layers/layer.py:224, in Layer.__new__.<locals>.build_wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    221 @wraps(original_build_method)
    222 def build_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    223     with backend.name_scope(obj.name, caller=obj):
--> 224         original_build_method(*args, **kwargs)
    225     # Record build config.
    226     signature = inspect.signature(original_build_method)

File /usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/keras/src/models/sequential.py:177, in Sequential.build(self, input_shape)
    175 for layer in self._layers[1:]:
    176     try:
--> 177         x = layer(x)
    178     except NotImplementedError:
    179         # Can happen if shape inference is not implemented.
    180         # TODO: consider reverting inbound nodes on layers processed.
    181         return

File /usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py:123, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
    120     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
    121     # To get the full stack trace, call:
    122     # `keras.config.disable_traceback_filtering()`
--> 123     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    124 finally:
    125     del filtered_tb

File /usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/keras/src/layers/input_spec.py:202, in assert_input_compatibility(input_spec, inputs, layer_name)
    200 if spec.min_ndim is not None:
    201     if ndim is not None and ndim < spec.min_ndim:
--> 202         raise ValueError(
    203             f'Input {input_index} of layer "{layer_name}" '
    204             "is incompatible with the layer: "
    205             f"expected min_ndim={spec.min_ndim}, "
    206             f"found ndim={ndim}. "
    207             f"Full shape received: {shape}"
    208         )
    209 # Check dtype.
    210 if spec.dtype is not None:

ValueError: Input 0 of layer "capa_de_salida" is incompatible with the layer: expected min_ndim=2, found ndim=1. Full shape received: (512,)

I'm using this docker container, which comes with tensorflow 2.16.1
sudo docker run -it --rm -v ./:/tf/notebooks -p 8888:8888 --runtime=nvidia tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu-jupyter


The error you're encountering when loading the saved model (ValueError: Input 0 of layer "capa_de_salida" is incompatible with the layer: expected min_ndim=2, found ndim=1) suggests that there is an inconsistency between the input shape expected by the layer "capa_de_salida" in your loaded model and the shape of the input data you're trying to feed into it.Before saving the model, print out the summary of the model (model.summary()) to see the shapes of the input and output of each layer. This will help you identify any inconsistencies

Ensure that the input data you're providing to the loaded model matches the shape it expects. In this case, it seems like the input to "capa_de_salida" layer is expected to have a minimum dimension of 2 (indicating a batch of samples), but it's receiving data with only 1 dimension.
